# Apex code to update email IDs after sandbox refresh

Tags: apex, user-management, sandbox-refresh

Please help me how to write apex code to update the user's emails id with apex class which can be run after sandbox refresh.

```
global static void run() { 

    List<User> userEmailList = [select Email from User where profile.name = ‘System Administrator’]; 

    for(User uc : userEmailList) 

    { 

        uc.Email = uc.Email.replace('=','@'); 
        String addedPhrase = '@example.com'; 
        uc.Email = uc.Email.remove(addedPhrase); 
        userEmailList.add(uc); 
    } 
    if(userEmailList.size() > 0) 
    { 
         Update userEmailList; 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Hello @Enriquez, welcome to SFSE. Your question is very general and thus difficult to answer. Additionally, there's a broad expectation here that you should show your research and the work you've done so far, rather than asking for others to do it for you. Could you expand on your question along those lines? ([How to Ask](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) is a good resource for formulating a good question).

Comment: I am trying the update the System admin email Id's after post refresh by using the following code, but unable to achieve it. Unable to figure out what am I missing

Comment: Sorry..missed my code in above comments

Comment: What exactly happens when you run this code? What, if any, error message do you receive? Again, please add this information to your question.

Comment: I found that email addresses aren't actually updated, but that confirmation emails are sent out to each updated user.  In a company with many sandboxes, this can get a bit spammy, so we wrote code to restrict this to targeted individuals as per sandbox name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a problem here:

```
List<User> userEmailList = [select Email from User where profile.name = ‘System Administrator’];
```

You're using Smart Quotes (`‘...’`), which won't compile in Apex Code. Replace them with apostrophes (`'`).

Minor detail: `if(userEmailList.size() > 0)` is not necessary.

In the future, avoid copying code to or from Office software (e.g. Microsoft Office, Open Office, etc), since they tend to modify your code in unexpected ways.

Comment: I used apostrophes, but still unable to save the class. I got an error stating Expecting '}' but was: 'for'. at line 3.

Comment: @Enriquez Did you put this code in a class? After fixing apostrophes, it worked fine in my org.

Comment: Thank you very much..I forgot I was  using other than global while defining class. Now i could save it.

Comment: Wouldn't this still give a runtime error on this line -- userEmailList.add(uc); ? as the collection is modified while being iterated.

Comment: @JayantDas Actually, I did overlook that. They'll need to remove that line of code, too.

Answer (score 1):

I did a quick and dirty, not polished code for this:

```
Contact[] contact2upd = new List <Contact>();

contact2upd = [SELECT ID, Email FROM Contact WHERE <your condition here - or all>];
for (Contact ctct : contact2upd) {
    String strEmail = ctct.Email;
    String strRegex = '@[a-z]+.[a-z]';
    String strReplace = '@noemail.c';
    String strEmailUpd = strEmail.replaceFirst(strRegex,strReplace);
    ctct.Email = strEmailUpd;
    }
update contact2upd;
```

Before enabling email deliverability in a sandbox better to make all contacts emails a non valid email. Particularly if you are using a Full Copy Sandbox.

It is not polished as the regex code it is not perfect: but it was a quick and dirty approximation: I only needed to replace quickly for an invalid email.

Hope it helps!